# turning off youtrack java process

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I have been running a trial version of youtrack on my windows pc couple months back. I would like to get rid of this.

It seems like there is a javaw.exe process with Username JetBrainsYouTrack consuming almost 1GB of memory on my computer. The program restarts with a restart of computer. There is no signature of an installed JetBrains program in control panel.

How do I remove this program from the computer?

Comment: Take a look at windows services list: WIN + R -> services.msc. There should be youtrack service running. Shut it down and change start type to 'manual'.

Comment: Thanks @Jk1. It worked

Answer (score -1):

Is there a folder in which the program has all of its files etc..?

I imagine there will be, if so, there will probably be an uninstall executable that you can run.